# 2 byte representation of command line arguments in Visual Studio 2008

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I have a problem when handling command line arguments in a simple C++ application written in Visual Studio 2008. I have written the following code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int _tmain(int argc, char **argv)
{
    char* c = *argv;    

    for(int i=0; i< argc ; ++i) 
    {
        cout << argv[i] << endl;
    }

    int a;
    cin >> a;

    return 0;    
}
```

My problem is that only the first character of each command line argument is written to `cout`.

I identified the cause to be that the characters in the command line arguments are represented as 2 bytes, making every other 1 byte `char` contain only zeros, i.e '\0'.

My question is, why do this happen? from what i found in samples on the net it should work as i have written it. Also, is there a way to force the characters in the arguments to be of 1 byte representation?

I hope my question is clear enough.

Comment: The signature of `_tmain` is `int _tmain(int argc, TCHAR** argv)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `_tmain` is receiving UTF-16 characters which, when fed Latin text, have a 0 in every other byte. You are interpreting them as single byte characters. You need to interpret them as wide characters.

I would write it something like this:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int wmain(int argc, wchar_t* argv[])
{
  for(int i=0; i<argc; ++i) 
  {
    wcout << argv[i] << endl;
  }

  int a;
  wcin >> a;

  return 0;
}
```

If you don't want to use UTF-16 then you can stick with `char` like this:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  for(int i=0; i<argc; ++i) 
  {
    cout << argv[i] << endl;
  }

  int a;
  cin >> a;

  return 0;
}
```

Note the change in the naming of the `main` function. In MS world, `wmain` receives `wchar_t*` and `main` receives `char*`.

If you do switch to `char*` then you should also update your project configuration to target MBCS rather than Unicode.

More information on the main function handling of the MS compiler can be found here: [main: Program Startup](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6wd819wh%28v=VS.90%29.aspx).

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer. If i do this, using the wizard, then send the VS2008-project to another person. Will the behavior be the same for him as when i run the program?

Comment: Yes it will be the same. In fact, I've changed my mind about the wizard. It uses TCHAR which is confusing an no longer needed. See my update (and the one I will do shortly).

Comment: One final thing. Make sure you update your project config to target MBCS rather than Unicode.